# Retrieving PSMultiValueSpecifier string from NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults

I have set up a preference using multi_preference in my Root.plist in my Settings.bundle as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>StringsTable</key>
    <string>Root</string>
    <key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSMultiValueSpecifier</string>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>multi_preference</string>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <string>Show First Page</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>My Option</string>
            <key>Identifier</key>
            <string>myOption</string>
            <key>Titles</key>
            <array>
                <string>Option 1</string>
                <string>Option 2</string>
            </array>
            <key>Values</key>
            <array>
                <string>Option 1</string>
                <string>Option 2</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

When I try to get the value from the list using the following code:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *option = [defaults arrayForKey:@"myOption"];
```

I always get nil returned.

I am using the simulator and I have set initial values in my applications settings.

Anybody got any ideas what I have missed out?

Thanks

iphaaw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for my previous answer, I misunderstood the question. Let's try this again.

Looking at [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Articles/PSMultiValueSpecifier.html) for PSMultiValueSpecifier, the key for NSUserPreferences is stored in the "Key" key in the plist, not the "Identifier" key. So in this case, `[defaults arrayForKey:@"multi_preference"]` should get you your value. Or you could change it like this and it should work with "myOption":

```
    <dict>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSMultiValueSpecifier</string>
        <key>Key</key>
        <string>myOption</string>
        <key>DefaultValue</key>
        <string>Option 1<string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>My Option</string>
        <key>Titles</key>
        <array>
            <string>Text for Option 1</string>
            <string>Text for Option 2</string>
        </array>
        <key>Values</key>
        <array>
            <string>Option 1</string>
            <string>Option 2</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

Comment: NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *mypref = [defaults arrayForKey:@"multi_preference"];

mypref returns nil.

If I write the defaults on startup with the following code it seems to work:
 
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Option 1" forKey:@"multi_preference"];
[defaults registerDefaults:appDefaults];
[defaults synchronize];

but this overwrites my prefs.

Comment: Does it work if you open the Settings application for your app before opening your application? If so, you simply need to use the `registerDefaults:` method on NSUserDefaults to specify the default values. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510216/can-you-make-the-settings-in-settings-bundle-default-even-if-you-dont-open-the-s) for help in loading the dictionary for `registerDefaults` from the settings bundle.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I don't know what happened. It seems that just renaming my key fixed my problem.

Comment: Very old question, so I'll simply add a comment. You're asking for an array but you should be asking for a string. The default type and each element of the array is a string. The array is used only to present the strings to the user. Retrieving the value returns a string.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431148/iphone-app-how-to-get-default-value-from-root-plist?lq=1)

The problem is the selected value is `nil` before user interacted with app settings.

The solution for this would be registering default values from Root.plist to `UserDefaults` when app launches.

I have updated the code of the original question to Swift 5:

```
static func registerSettingsDefaults()
{
    // Get Settings bundle path
    guard let settingsBundle = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Settings", ofType: "bundle") else {
        assertionFailure("Could not find Settings bundle")
        return
    }

    // Get settings plist
    let settings = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: settingsBundle + "/Root.plist")

    // Get preferences dictionary
    guard let preferences = settings?.object(forKey: "PreferenceSpecifiers") as? [[String: Any]] else {
        assertionFailure("Could not find preferences")
        return
    }

    // Filter out default values from Settings
    var defaultsToRegister: [String: Any] = [:]
    preferences.forEach { dictionary in
        if let key = dictionary["Key"] as? String {
            defaultsToRegister[key] = dictionary["DefaultValue"] as? String
        }
    }

    UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: defaultsToRegister)
}
```

And I call it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
{
    // Register Settings defaults
    registerSettingsDefaults()
```