# How to migrate NSUserDefaults in new release?

Tags: iphone, preferences, nsuserdefaults

I have an iPhone app that stores some settings using `NSUserDefault standardUserDefaults`.

When I add new features to the app I need to add new default settings and so I have to migrate/upgrade the `NSUserDefaults`. For now, I just *store the version number* and check this when the app is launched. It has quickly become very messy as I have to add lots of *if* statements. I cannot assume that the user is just upgrading from the previous version but *perhaps even a couple of versions* before.

I like the way that CoreData seems to handle migrating table changes but I want to provide 2.2.1 SDK compatibility and of course CoreData is not the same thing as `NSUserDefaults`.

Any suggestions or best practices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm… I wouldn't "upgrade" the user defaults in this way, but instead query NSUserDefaults as usual, only if the default isn't set (objectForKey will return nil in that case), use a default value (which may then be written back to the user defaults to save time the next time). Since you'll have to do this every time a "new" default (i.e. one that didn't exist in 1.0) is read, I advise doing a wrapper class/file that does this, this way the code is written only once for each "new" default.

Also, while the question/problem is different, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546005/iphone-and-nsuserdefaults/1546016#1546016) works just as well in your case.