# Why is this simple settings bundle not reading anything?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, settings, application-settings

I have a settings bundle with the following settings. When I build/install my app the Settings.app appears to work correctly. I see the default value and everything. But in my app when trying to read the text field's text I get nil.

[image]

Here is how I read the settings

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSString *temp = [defaults stringForKey:@"url_preference"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The defaults in the settings bundle are only read by the Settings app.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510216/can-you-make-the-settings-in-settings-bundle-default-even-if-you-dont-open-the-s) for details and workarounds.

Comment: Thanks, sure seems like a PITA that it works this way. Perhaps it shouldn't be called DefaultValue and instead PlaceHolderValue to be inline with other iOS things.

Comment: Yeah, I think it trips up more or less everybody the first time.  Definitely a badly designed API.