# How to work with Settings.bundle

Tags: ios, settings

I'm developing an iOS app with latest SDK.

I have created a `Settings.bundle` with a `Root.plist` and another four `.plist` and every setting on these files have each default value.

This is the first time I work with `Settings.bundle` and I'm lost. I have found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510216/can-you-make-the-settings-in-settings-bundle-default-even-if-you-dont-open-the) where they said that I have to read `Settings.bundle` defaults values every time I run the application and I don't understand why.

I think I have to continue using `NSUserDefaults` here to read settings values.

I have these questions:

1. How can I read the values set on these settings using Setting app?
2. How can I know if the user changes one or more of these values? The user makes the app to goes background, open Setting app and change something. How can I know that programmatically?
3. How can I save any modification (a change in a setting value) and see that change on Settings app?

By the way, now I have this code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Set the application defaults
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (![defaults boolForKey:@"firstRun"])
    {
        NSDictionary *appDefaults = [PreferenceDefaultValues dictionary];
        [defaults registerDefaults:appDefaults];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"firstRun"];

        [defaults synchronize];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. The `identifier` of any preference item in the Settings.bundle plist can be accessed with `NSUserDefaults`. For example, if you have a preference item with an identifier named `allowDiagnostics`, then you can access the value for that item with `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"allowDiagnostics"]` (assuming that it was a `BOOL` item).
2. You can use the `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification` to get notified of any changes to your preferences.
3. The same way you read them. To continue the example of 1, `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"allowDiagnostics"]`. Note though, that allowing the user to change options from multiple places (Settings.bundle and somewhere in your app), can be confusing to the user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I have to do `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:appDefaults];` every time my app starts?

Comment: I usually put that line of code in my `applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions`